# fetchone() for login returning 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable but register is working

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask

I am getting **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable** error
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Folder\Major project\shopping\app.py", line 34, in login
Open an interactive python shell in this frameif account[3] == pass_wd:

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        if request.method == 'POST':
             session.pop('user_id', None)

            u_id = request.form["uid"]
            pass_wd = request.form["passwd"]

            qur = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email = \"{}\" ".format(u_id)
    
    
            mycursor.execute(qur)
            account = mycursor.fetchone()
            mydb.commit()
    
            if account[3] == pass_wd:
                session['loggedin'] = True
                session['id'] = account[0]
                session['username'] = account[1]
                mycursor.execute('SELECT name FROM logins WHERE email = %s', (u_id,))
                account = mycursor.fetchall()
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                print(account[0], pass_wd)
                return 'Wrong id or pass word'
        return render_template("login.html")


    @app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def register():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.form["username"]
            password = request.form["password"]
            email = request.form["email"]
            sql = "INSERT INTO logins (name, email, password) VALUES (\"{}\", \"{}\", \"{}\")"
            mycursor.execute(sql.format(name, email, password))
            mydb.commit()
            mob_names = [item[0] for item in rows]
            a = [item[1] for item in rows]
            return render_template("tp.html", data = mob_names, img = a, name = name)
        return render_template("register.html")
```

'''

Comment: You don´t need to do a commit after executing a select. Your error means that your account variable is empty (None type) so yoy didn´t get any result from your query. And try to use prepared statements to avoid sql injections

Comment: Completely agree with the above. In addition you can combine two select statements in one eg: `SELECT name, some_other_field FROM logins WHERE email = 'something' AND password = 'hashed password'`. In 2021 there is no excuse for writing code that is vulnerable to **SQL injections** and storing **passwords in clear text**. Hash them. Last but not least, the E-mail address should probably be a primary key, meaning that it should be unique in the table of users.